# Execute same command in multiple subdirectories

Tags: bash, fortran

I've written a fortran script that I would like to run in over 200 directories. The directories are all named case_1, case_2, etc. I wanted to know if there is a command I can run so that this script is executed in all of these sub-directories. I do not want to execute this command 200 times.

Thanks!

Comment: adjust your command/script, let it accept parameter/argument, which is a dir, then you could either do with a loop, or use `find|xargs cmd`

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I would like to write a BASH script that runs the Fortran program in each of the 200 directorires. Much thanks.

Comment: Hi Kent, could you elaborate, with an example perhaps? I'm not as familiar with using the find command, although it appears to be a powerful tool.

Comment: e.g. `find . -type f|xargs rm` remove all files. you get thousand if you google

Comment: do I need to source my executable in the bashrc if I want to run it like rm is run in your example?

Comment: You don't want to execute the command 200 times **manually** or you don't want to execute the command 200 times at all? If former is the case it is simple bash script that can run it 200 times sequentially (one after the other) or concurrently (you have to say what you want). If later is the case you would have to alter your program.

Comment: wow Kent thats a dangerous example.  @user2044576 can you give a more explict description of how you would do this manually. Do you simply cd to each directory and execute the fortran with no arguments?

Answer (score 2):

[GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) might be useful here. Untested:

```
parallel 'cd {} && yourProgram' ::: case_*
```

Comment: 10 seconds installation: wget -O - pi.dk/3|sh

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
for dir in case_*
do
    cd $dir
    /path/to/fortran/command
    cd .. # <- EDIT: This brings you back to the original directory
done
```

This should get you started.

Comment: dont you need a cd .. in there? Or does bash do take care of that?

Comment: @george Right, there should be a `cd` back to the original directory